# Dúvida com erro - comparações contra strings

Tags: javascript

Olá,
Boa Tarde!

Estou em uma plataforma de estudos no qual se executa exercícios e testes, o enunciado é:

> Escreva a função pode `SeAposentar` que recebe por parâmetro a idade, o sexo e os anos de contribuição previdenciária que uma pessoa tem, exemplo:
>   `podeSeAposentar(62, "F", 34) true`.
>
> A idade mínima para se aposentar para mulheres é 60 anos, enquanto que para homens é 65. Em ambos os casos, deve ter pelo menos 30 anos de contribuição.

**Fiz o seguinte código:**

```js
function podeSeAposentar (idade, sexo, anosTrabalhados) {
    if(anosTrabalhados >= 40) {
        if(sexo == "F") {
            if(idade >= 60) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        else if(sexo == "M") {
            if(idade>= 65){
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

E a plataforma informa que:

> Sua solução funcionou, mas aponta o seguinte erro:
>
> Objetivos que não foram atendidos:
>    `podeSeAposentar` faz comparações contra strings.

Alguém poderia me ajudar e pq acontece isso?
Grata!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O código pode ser simplificado desta forma:

```
function podeSeAposentar(idade, sexo, anosTrabalhados) {
    return anosTrabalhados >= 40 && idade >= (sexo === 'F' ? 60 : 65);
}
```

Se ele continuar reclamando, você pode substituir isso:

```
sexo === 'F'
```

Por isso:

```
sexo.charCodeAt(0) === 70
```

Comment: Finalmente a plataforma aceitou, colocando: sexo.charCodeAt(0) === 70. Grata!

Answer (score 0):

Pode usar de formas mais "diferentes", por exemplo, no caso, não utilizando strings ("mas que não diferencia muito, pois o valor pode ser 'm' e 'f'"):

```js
const MASCULINO = 0;
const FEMININO = 1;

function podeSeAposentar(idade, sexo, anosTrabalhados) {
    if (anosTrabalhados <= 30) {
        return false;
    }

    switch (sexo) {
        case FEMININO:
            return idade >= 60;
            break;

        case MASCULINO:
            return idade >= 65;
            break;
    }
}
```

*Obs.: Mudei o anosTrabalhados para 30, por conta de: "...deve ter pelo menos 30 anos de contribuição"*

Answer (score 0):

A observação está tentando te dizer que você deveria converter os valores numéricos para números antes de usá-los em comparações.

Você pode usar a função [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) para converter strings para números inteiros.

```
function podeSeAposentar (idade, sexo, anosTrabalhados) {
    // Converte valores númericos para Number
    anosTrabalhados = parseInt(anosTrabalhados, 10);
    idade = parseInt(idade, 10);

    // Agora sim realiza os teste
    if (sexo === 'M') {
        return anosTrabalhados >= 30 && idade >= 65;
    } else {
        return anosTrabalhados >= 30 && idade >= 60;
    }
}
```

<sup>*PS: as únicas comparações do seu código são com os 3 parâmetros que sua função define, apesar do enunciado explicitar o exemplo `podeSeAposentar(62, "F", 34)`, se esta observação está ocorrendo é porque a plataforma passa os números como string, ao contrário do que ela mesmo afirma no próprio enunciado.*</sup>

Comment: Fernando, pois é, e fazendo desta forma ou da outra o erro faz comparações contra strings permanece. O que fazer?

Comment: Acho que o mais importante é você passar o link desse exercício... Assim é mais fácil de analisar... Fiz o que pude com o que estava escrito na pergunta. :D

Comment: Fernando, é este: https://mumuki.io/br/exercises/4511-programacao-imperativa-logica-booleana-um-exercicio-sem-precedentes

Comment: O site deles tem bug, acabei de postar minha solução lá e diz: "a solução deve declarar uma função podeSeAposentar". Rode seu código no navegador ou https://codepen.io e teste você mesmo.

Comment: Sim, mas como a plataforma de estudos é lá, mesmo rodando ok em outros neste precisaria fazer funcionar kkk. :/

Comment: Eu acabei de definir uma função `podeSeAposentar`, e o site rodou todos os teste na minha função (que passou em todos os teste)... Aí tem uma observação dizendo que eu tenho que criar uma função chamada "podeSeAposentar". O que eu quero dizer com isso é o que o site tem bug, e talvez sua pergunta nunca fosse aberta se não houvesse este bug. Se sua nota em faculdade ou curso depende dessa plataforma, você deveria entrar em contato com seus professores, fora isso eu só posso ajudar a resolver problema que realmente existem no seu código. O bug deles não sei como resolver. :|

Comment: Grata pelas dicas e ajuda Fernando!

Answer (score 0):

a minha resposta pra essa questão é:

```
function podeSeAposentar(idade, sexo, anosContrib) {
    return (sexo == "M" && idade >= 65 && anosContrib >= 30) || (sexo == "F" && idade >= 60 && anosContrib >= 30)
}
```